# Postgres: How can I query and see if a client connection is ssl-encrypted?

Tags: postgresql, ssl

In a query, I can use inet_server_addr() to return the server's IP address.

What can I use in my query to determine if the connection is ssl-encrypted, e.g.

```
select inet_server_addr() as 'server_inet_address', ??? as 'connection_ssl_status';
```

Comment: Use `pg_stat_ssl`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-SSL-VIEW

Comment: via https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/225872/how-to-verify-ssl-always-being-used-on-postgresql-9-6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From @DanielVérité's answer in this DBA QA: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/225915/10044

> At runtime, to check which sessions are encrypted, there's the `pg_stat_ssl` system view (since PostgreSQL 9.5). Its `pid` column is a reference to `pg_stat_activity` that holds the other bits of information that might be relevant to identifying the connection such as `usename`, `datname`, `client_addr`..., so you might use this query, for instance:
>
> ```sql
> SELECT
>     datname,
>     usename,
>     ssl,
>     client_addr 
> FROM
>     pg_stat_ssl
>     INNER JOIN pg_stat_activity ON pg_stat_ssl.pid = pg_stat_activity.pid;
> ```